# set a picture as a background for every layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5, photoshop-cs6

I have a website where I store images on black background of fixed dimensions.Yesterday I got a lot of new images with inappropriate shape. I want to change the dimensions in photoshop. I export all of them to photoshop and their background becomes transparent, so after my handling and saving all images to jpg, their background becomes white.
Tell me please how can I make black background with fixed dimensions for each image in one step without loops?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the images with transparent background. If the image layer is a Background layer right click on it and select Layer from Background.

Create a new layer and fill it with black using the Paint Bucket tool.

Drag the new layer below the image layer. Merge the layers before saving.

You can record an action while you do these steps, to be able to apply it to any other image with a single click.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html